# django - exit and redirect to homepage in the middle of form wizard

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have a form wizard consisting of a few forms (Django 1.4). I am trying to check some condition in `process_step` function (for a intermediate step), exit form wizard and redirect to the homepage. When I try to redirect with `HttpResponseRedirect(<homepage>)` at the end of `process_step` function, it ignores and proceeds to the next form step.

Comment: > When I try to redirect with HttpResponseRedirect(<homepage>)

What's the code? How do you try this?

Answer (score 0):

For Django to actually render the next step, it needs to do a return `HttpResponse`, or `return render_to_response`, etc.  So most likely the control flow is simply never getting to the `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Answer (score 0):

Process_step only processes data, what it returns isn't ever rendered. Probably your best bet is to override render_next_step, though you could handle it with a couple other functions as well.

So, override render_next_step, and do something like:

```
    def render_next_step(self, form, **kwargs):
        data = get_cleaned_data('2')  # or whatever your step with the flag is
        if data.get('your_flag', False):
            self.storage.reset()
            return HttpResponseRedirect()
        return super(Wizard, self).render_next_step(self, form, **kwargs)
```

You may also want to add a condition before getting cleaned data, to check what the current or next step is.